# OleDBConnection error

Tags: database, vb.net, runtime-error, oledb

I've been working on a computing project in Visual Basic 2010 and I've encountered a error and I cannot find the problem causing it.
Whenever I try to save to my database I get a error in my OleDBConnection.vb form with the following
This is my Code

```
Class OleDbConnection

    Private _p1 As Object

    Sub New(ByVal p1 As Object)
        ' TODO: Complete member initialization 
        _p1 = p1
    End Sub


    Sub Close()
        Throw New NotImplementedException
    End Sub

    Sub Open()
        **Throw New NotImplementedException**
    End Sub

End Class
```

my original code for the saving of the project to the database is

```
 Public Class AddClass
        Public Shared connectionString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data 
Source=C:\Users\Sami\Desktop\F454\VB_PrototypeDB.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub


    Private Sub DataView()
        Throw New NotImplementedException
    End Sub

        Private Sub PictureBox1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Click
        Me.Hide()
        MMenu.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub PictureBox2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles PictureBox2.Click
        Dim cn As New OleDbConnection(connectionString)

        cn.Open()
        Dim ClassName As String = TextBox1.Text
        Dim Subject As String = ComboBox1.Text()
        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Class (ClassName, Subject) VALUES ('" & ClassName & "', '" & Subject & "') ')", cn)

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        cn.Close()

        Call MsgBox("Student Has Been Saved", 0, "Student Database")

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: what error occured...

Comment: Throw New NotImplementedException

Comment: pls give me code for :::                                         Sub Close()
        Throw New NotImplementedException
    End Sub

    Sub Open()
        **Throw New NotImplementedException**
    End Sub

Comment: I am not surprised. You call a method, which throws the NotImplementedException. What did you expect? And why do you implement a Class called OleDbConnection. Why do you not use the already defined class System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection?